# How change color of a given section on all toc frames of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am using the following code at different places in my beamer presentation:

```latex
\begin{frame}{Sommaire du jour}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
```

In all those frames, I want the specific section, let's say the third one, to appear highlighted. For example with a bigger font and a custom color.

How can I achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Sommaire du jour}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section[title2]{\texorpdfstring{\color{red}}{}title2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```